# How to initialize a doubly linked list with the following structs?

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

This is my code, I know I did not write much, but I am not knowing how to initialize a doubly linked list with the given structs.

The given structs (I can`t change anything in them)

```
/* a node in the linked list */
typedef struct Node
{
    void *data;
    struct Node *next;
    struct Node *prev;
} Node;

/* a linked list */
typedef struct LinkedList
{
    Node *head;
    Node *tail;
} LinkedList;
```

And this is my code

```
/* create a new linked list */
/* returns a pointer to the newly created list */
/* print an error message and return NULL if an error occurs */
LinkedList *initialise_linked_list(void)
{
    LinkedList *list;
    list = (LinkedList *)malloc(sizeof(LinkedList));
        if (list == 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Warning: Memory could not be allocated for the new created list.");
            printf("\n");
            return 0;
        }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Aside: Nice alternative to `list = (LinkedList *)malloc(sizeof(LinkedList));` is `list = malloc(sizeof *list);`

Comment: You only need to either call `calloc`, or set `head` and `tail` to`NULL`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it the following way

```
LinkedList initialise_linked_list(void)
{
    LinkedList list = { NULL, NULL };
    return list;
}
```

and call the function like

```
LinkedList list = initialise_linked_list();
```

Another approach is the following

```
void initialise_linked_list( LinkedList *list )
{
    list->head = NULL;
    list->tail = NULL;  
}
```

and call it like

```
LinkedList list;
initialise_linked_list( &list );
```

There is no need to allocate the list itself dynamically. It is nodes of the list that will be allocated dynamically.

As for your function then it does not initialize a linked list. It just allocates memory for the structure. At least instead of `malloc` you should use `calloc`.

For example

```
LinkedList * initialise_linked_list( void )
{
    LinkedList *list = calloc( 1, sizeof( LinkedList ) );

    if ( list == NULL )
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Warning: Memory could not be allocated for the new created list.\n");
    }

    return list;
}
```

Comment: yes but I can`t change the parameters for the function, I can only write inside the block { }

Comment: and does this correctly create a doubly linked list? if I only set the head and tail to 0 ?

Comment: @Tomiisme This is the initialization of the linked list.

Comment: Vlad, a program that manages many lists, or has a list of lists, would prefer a `malloc`d `LinkedList` implementation

Comment: @Tomiisme You should write at least one more function that will add nodes to the initialized list.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie There is no such a structure in the question.